# webpack using the ejs loader

Tags: webpack, ejs, webpack-2

I'm trying to use webpack to recompose an HTML page using ejs.
With the config below I'm getting the error.

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry: ['./pages/index.ejx'],
    output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"         
    },  
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'pages/index.ejs'})
    ]
}
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <% include ..partials/head %>

    <% include ..partials/body %>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This config seems to work so far:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry: ['./index.ejs'],
    output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"         
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ejs$/, loader: "ejs-render-loader" } 

        ]
    },  
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'index.ejs'
            })
        ]
}
```

Comment: do you have data inside the index? like ```<%- data %>```